# A better way of iterating and filling data in HTML table using Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, performance

I have a table which might contain up to 50 rows and has 9 columns. However the code I am using to fill out data in the table its taking so long.

Is there a faster way of doing it?
 Here is my code

```
table = $browser.div(:id => "market").table(:id => 'tableTradeIndMarket')
  i = 3 + rand(1..table.rows.length-4)      

      table.rows[i].cells[4].select_list.select 'Buy'     
      table.rows[i].cells[5].select_list.select 'Market'          
      table.rows[i].cells[6].text_field.set ($share) 


      table.rows[i+1].cells[4].select_list.select 'Buy'       
      table.rows[i+1].cells[5].select_list.select 'Limit'     
      table.rows[i+1].cells[6].text_field.set ($share) 
      //To take out dollar sign which is found on the second column and put that value in to another column of the same row
      table.rows[i+1].cells[8].text_field.set(
        table.rows[i+1].cells[2].text[1..table.rows[i+1].cells[2].text.length]
      ) 

      table.rows[i+1].cells[9].select_list.select 'Day'  

      table.rows[i+2].cells[4].select_list.select 'Buy'       
      table.rows[i+2].cells[5].select_list.select 'Stop'      
      table.rows[i+2].cells[6].text_field.set ($share) 
      table.rows[i+2].cells[7].text_field.set ( table.rows[i+2].cells[2].text[1..table.rows[i+2].cells[2].text.length]) 
      table.rows[i+2].cells[9].select_list.select 'GTC'  

      table.rows[i+3].cells[4].select_list.select 'Buy'       
      table.rows[i+3].cells[5].select_list.select 'Stop/Limit'    
      table.rows[i+3].cells[6].text_field.set ($share) 
      table.rows[i+3].cells[7].text_field.set ( table.rows[i+3].cells[2].text[1..table.rows[i+3].cells[2].text.length]) 
      table.rows[i+3].cells[8].text_field.set ( table.rows[i+3].cells[2].text[1..table.rows[i+3].cells[2].text.length]) 
      table.rows[i+3].cells[9].select_list.select 'Day'
```

Comment: Can you provide with a source code of the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to locate the row element with the help of Nokogiri. Željko Filipin had a good blog post about doing this - http://zeljkofilipin.com/watir-nokogiri

As an example, the inputting of your ith row would be:

```
row_css = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html).at_css("table#tableTradeIndMarket tr:nth-of-type(#{i})").css_path
row = browser.element(:css, row_css).to_subtype
row.cells[4].select_list.select 'Buy'     
row.cells[5].select_list.select 'Market'          
row.cells[6].text_field.set ($share)
```

You could apply the same concept to the other rows that you are inputting.

This helped at least for the test table that I was using.